# can I undo event.stopPropagation

Tags: jquery, events

As a n00b with jQuery, I hope this question makes sense!

I have a menu created as nested tables. Occasionally I wish to disable it. (Show hourglass cursor, etc.)

Each menu item is really a `<td>` inside of another . Fortunately, the inner `<td>` responds to the click event, so applying `event.stopPropagation()` to the `td.class` that identifies the outer `<td>`s very nicely prevents menu items from responding to clicks.

But under some circumstances, I want to withdraw? suspend? undo? turn off? the `stopPropagation()` so the inner `<td>`'s Click handlers see the click events again. I want the click event to bubble again.

To do this, I think I want to "undo" the `stopPropagation()` on the outer `<td>`s. This must be possible, right? The fact that I can't find a way to do this tells me there might be something wrong with the way I am approaching this.

So, is there a way? And if not, am I thinking about this erroneously? Thanks.

Paragram

```
 <td onclick="javascript: myhandler();"><table><tr>
<td class="menuitems">Menu Item</td></tr></table></td>
```

Comment: Can you show a larger sample of your code, perhaps at http://jsfiddle.net, including the part that calls `stopPropagation()`? If you are stopping propagation from the outer elements the inner ones _will_ see the click events. (Also why do you have inline onclick handlers when you're using jQuery?)

Answer (score 0):

You can put `event.stopPropagation()` conditionally.

Whenever you want to stop the bubbling just make sure that statement will execute. In matching case make sure that it will not execute.

Any ways you'll be having some conditions to undo the `event.stopPropagation()` Then why not in this way??

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can suggest trying to add `.not(".class_to_exclude")` before the `event.stopPropagation()`, to exclude that class of `<td>`'s